# Power BI - Create a New Column that Repeat Some Line Information

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a report that export some data in the same column (for example, the material type and its production line), however I need this information in separate columns. In Excel, I would use a IF formula (attached), but in Power BI I don't know if is it possible to do in the same way.

In Excel, I used this formula:

```
=IF(A7="Finished Goods";A7;
IF(A7="Raw Material";"Raw Material";
IF(A7="Consumables";"Consumables";C6)))
```

that has this result:
[image]

But in PBI I can't select the cell from the line above.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Write a calculate column using switch in DAX

```
Classification = SWITCH(TRUE(),
Table[report] = "Finished Goods", "Finished Goods",
Table[report] = "Raw Material", "Raw Material",
"Consumables"
```

Then go to PowerQuery -> Transform -> Fill -> Down and fill the cells in classification column